# Firefox debugger does not step through javascript

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox

When breakpoint fires, the page gets an overlay if the debugger had started. But it does not show the current code location.

It happend after recent update 113.0.2. I also tried the dev 114 version. Then uninstalled and installed 113 completely again.

The issue seems to be something with ignoring JS-files. After reinstallation the debugger steps through code as expected. But when I ignore some source, the issue occurs.

I've searched also for a list of ignored sources in Firefox as e. g. in Chrome but could not find any.

Comment: *with particular websites* ... so, not a "global" issue? Have you tried the dev build (114) to see if the issue persists?

Comment: I normally would clear the cache

Comment: I cleared cache, refereshed Firefox, reinstalled twice ...