# Debugger problems after recent Firefox update

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox

It seems that the recent update of Firefox (113.02) has some issues with debugging javascript: though the debugger starts, the steps are not tracked!

I had this issue a on computer where update was installed. Then I tested on another computer where the old version was installed. It worked as expected. Just after updating, the same issue occured here as well.

Though I am not sure, the problem is global. The issue occurs at least on this particular [site](https://dme.mozarteum.at/movi/en).

Possibly relates to ignoring source files and directories.

Comment: Yes, looks like they messed something up, someone already "reported" it here yesterday - https://stackoverflow.com/q/76363585/1427878 Not sure what actual question here is supposed to be here now though.

Comment: The question is: if it is indeed the Update or something else?